# Move files from one SharePoint site to another based on tags

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I asked this question yesterday, but with a guest account, so i was unable to reply to the answers.

I want to be able to upload a batch of documents to a folder, tag them with client names and document type, and have a flow move each file to a specific client site where they can only see files associated with them. Is this possible with a flow? It is worth noting we have our Document library set up with a folder structure that has multiple levels. Would that make this more challenging?

An example would be Daniel receives documents for two clients, Chris and Mike. Daniel drags the files to a SharePoint folder that corresponds with where the files are coming from, tags one file as type="Financial" and client="Mike" and the other as type="Personal" client="Chris" - a flow then moves these files based on the tags... Later that day Chris logs on and sees the file that was uploaded as well as the type of file that it is. Chris only sees his files, he does not see files tagged for Mike.

Please let me know if any additional details are needed. our folder structure is sorted by business we get the documents from --> type ---> year if that makes sense.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

**Just one suggestion:** If you want to manage files based on clients’ permissions, an easier way would be to create separate document libraries or separate folders in a library, instead of breaking inheritance using flow.

Every document moved to the folder will automatically inherit permission from the folder.

Here’s a sample flow for only two clients/destination folders:

(Any document created in this library will trigger the flow and will be moved based on the property values and corresponding conditions in the flow.)

[image]